# Several android applications with same look&feel

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I have the following situation:

Two (for the moment) simple android applications.
I want these applications to have a "common look & feel":

- same header
- same footer
- similar sliding menu
- similar favourite screen

So I've extracted common components in a library project.
I've created a base activity with the common header, footer, menu, favourite screen.

But I'm not sure that it's possible to add the 'specific for application things' by just inheritance of the base activity and overriding.
It looks like dynamic UI generation depending on the app...

Maybe the inheritance of base activity is not the way.
Maybe some predefined interfaces in the library and implemetation in the specific application.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest create simple style files and copy the styles across multiple application. Other approach would be to create ui library and with required component and implement it in the other app and and instead of using android components use your own components

Comment: @ManojMohanty, Yes, I have a UI library with my components.
That's not a problem and it's ok.
But I'm not sure that my idea with the activity in the library and only specific UI in the applications is possible.

If this was not a UI I think it would not be a problem with interfaces defined in a library and specific implementation in applications...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make only 1 activity or fragment, for the same looking. And in your XML make 2 diff layouts for each one (Header, footer, sliding menu are common).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Header Layout -->
    <!-- Footer Layout -->
    <!-- Menu Layout -->
    
    <!-- Layout 1 for app1 functionality -->
    <!-- Layout 2 for app2 functionality -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, where you are redirecting to activity, pass one additional value for identifying from which one this is opening.

For example:
Suppose, your common class is similar to this:

```
class Common(private val isFromApp1: Boolean) : AppCompatActivity() {
}
```

In onCreate function of Common class check:

```
if(isFromApp1)
     layout1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
else
     layout2.visibility = View.GONE
```

Handle all things just from one class, that's it.

Comment: It would mean that the common activity (in the library) should know about the list of applications which use this library common activity, right ?